# File explorer GUI for a running docker container?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to have a GUI file explorer (e.g. like winscp/windows or nautilus/linux) on my host machine that can show the filesystem of a running docker container?

Primarily interested in a GUI for Linux/Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Docker uses cgroups for isolation.

You should be able to browse the docker container's filesystem directly via the `procfs`. Specifically, if you browse `/proc/<pid>/root/`, where `<pid>` is the PID of a process within the container.

From the [Moby issue tracker](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26872#issuecomment-249315020):

```
docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} $YOUR_CONTAINER
```

Should give you a PID.

Therefore, from the command line, you could `cd` into:

```
/proc/$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} $YOUR_CONTAINER)/root
```

You should then be able to browse to that same directory from your GUI file browser. However, you likely will not be able to use the `$()` construct directly, which leaves you with either:

- Using a CLI to launch a GUI file explorer pointing to that path

or

- Using a CLI to retrieve the PID and then browse directly there in the GUI, e.g. `/proc/123/root`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't actually *have* X installed so I can't test either method. However, if, say, Nautilus refuses to browse into `/proc` you can always symlink a different directory to there and browse to that one. Or you can bind mount it. etc etc ...